Is it possible to define shared field resolvers across different types in GraphQL?
I have some types that essentially extend a base type. I know GraphQL doesn't exactly support that so I am using an interface to define the base class, and then implementing it in both a base type and extended type. It has the benefit of allowing me to use shared fragments. However, I was hoping I could define resolvers off the interface instead of in each individual type. Is there a way to define shared resolvers through GraphQL itself?
union Object = BaseObject | ObjectA | ObjectB

interface ObjectI {
  id: ID!
  relationalField: SomeOtherObject!
  ...
}

type BaseObject implements ObjectI {
  id: ID!
  relationalField: SomeOtherObject!
  ...
}

type ObjectA implements ObjectI {
  id: ID!
  relationalField: SomeOtherObject!
  ...
  # more fields
  uniqueA: String!
}

type ObjectB implements ObjectI {
  id: ID!
  relationalField: SomeOtherObject!
  ...
  # more fields
  uniqueB: String!
}

export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    objects: async (parent, args, context, info) => dataSource.get(),
  },
  Object: {
    __resolveType: (obj) => defineType(obj),
  },
  ObjectI: {
    // this is what I am trying to do that doesn't work
    relationalField: async (parent, args, context, info) => dataSource.getSomeOtherObject(parent),
  },
  // instead I have to define that resolver 3 times in each type
  BaseObject: { },
  ObjectA: { }, 
  ObjectB: { },
}

I realize I can create a function variable somewhere else that I call in each resolver. It works. But just wondering if there is a way to define common resolvers through GraphQL hierarchy?
:bleh:
  BaseObject: {
    relationalField: async (parent, args, context, info) => dataSource.getSomeOtherObject(parent),
  },
  ObjectA: {
    relationalField: async (parent, args, context, info) => dataSource.getSomeOtherObject(parent),
  }, 
  ObjectB: {
    relationalField: async (parent, args, context, info) => dataSource.getSomeOtherObject(parent),
  },


FYI: "resolvers" aren't really a GraphQL question. They're not even in the GraphQL specification. That is an implementation-specific question. This question has nothing to do with GraphQL, aside from the fact that the layer in front of your question is GraphQL.

Looking at your code, I assume you're using Apollo Server, which makes this a JavaScript (or TypeScript) question, so you can do whatever you want. For example, you could use some GenericTypeResolver class, or you could make a resolver factory.
interface GenericResolvers<T> {
  loadById(id: string): T;
  loadAll(): T[];
  deleteById(id: string): T;
}

type EntityModel = typeof User | typeof Book | typeof Author;

const genericTypeResolverFactory = <T extends EntityModel>(model: T): GenericResolvers<T> => {
  const dataSource = new DataSource<T>(model);

  return {
    loadById: (id: string) => dataSource.loadById(id),
    loadAll: () => dataSource.loadAll(),
    deleteById: (id: string) => dataSource.deleteById(id),
  }
}

const resolvers = {
  User: genericTypeResolverFactory(User),
  Book: genericTypeResolverFactory(Book),
  Author: genericTypeResolverFactory(Author),
}

Or even
const resolvers = [User, Book, Author].reduce((acc, model) => {
  acc[model.constructor.name] = genericTypeResolverFactory(model);
  return acc;
}, {} as Record<string, GenericResolvers<EntityModel>>);


Caveat: depending on the version of Apollo or graphql-js you're using, you may need to be mindful of "extra fields". If you're using a class with other methods, those are all functionally "resolvers", whether you meant for them to be or not, and some tools will complain if you have resolvers for properties that aren't in your schema. This is one reason why a factory is sometimes preferred over a class.
